# Subpanel has broken hot and the other hot, neutral and ground are good. Can I just run one feeder wire to the subpanel and use the other feeder wires

Tags: electrical

if one feeder is broken. Can I run one feeder wire to use with the existing good feeder wires

Comment: Is the feeder in conduit (a tube or pipe with individual wires in it), or is it a cable (multiple wires in one overall jacket?)

Comment: It underground from the house running under a driveway and it looks like the 3 aluminum wires are in a conduit. I get 120v on one hot leg. I also have to place a ground rod at garage  separate the neutrals from the grounds. The so-called Licensed Electrician didn't run a 4 wire. So, the garage subpanel was fed with two hots and a neutral acting as ground as well. I have to get a new feeder hot wire from house main service panel to the garage subpanel and place a ground rod. This so-called Licensed Electrician did whatever he wanted with no regard for the NEC.

Comment: If understanding correctly, you can just use one hot feeder, but it will limit you to just having 120 volt circuits.

Comment: Yes, I need 220v.  I can run an entire new feeder but I am trying to save customer money

Comment: For 220 which is really 240 volts you need two hot feeders.  Will need to replace the broken feeder, but maybe one of the electricians knows of a way of repairing it.

Comment: I know 240 and that I have to replace broken hot wire. I want to know if I can just run one new feeder and use it with the good existing feeder

Comment: it's underground and the subpanel need a ground wire from the main service panel and a ground rod. Unless I can just place a ground rod and ground wire at the garage and use the neutral wire as a hot wire. But, I will still have the same 2 hots and a ground like it is now.

Comment: I think I will do what I was going to do. Run a 4 wire feeder from main panel to subpanel and place a ground rod. Then, I will have the correct 2 hots, 1 neutral and 1 ground.  Thanks anyway. I just wanted to save the homeowner money. Copper is expensive just like gas and everything else

Comment: What size conduit, metal or PVC, length of run?

Comment: length of run is probably 100ft + and I see an LB that seems to be 1" but I am not sure. Everything is underground

Comment: metal or PVC conduit?

Comment: PVC. I thought of pulling another feeder but I have no idea where it goes when it leaves outside from the LB. I see it at the main panel running through a pvc pipe and then I see the individual legs coming out of the pvc pipe and then turns right up in the sheet rock ceiling.  I was going to run new feeder on the outside of house then underground to the garage then in pvc pipe inside the garage to the subpanel

Comment: Is the PVC just a stub-up for a buried cable line? Or is it conduit the whole way? If it's conduit, pull out the 3 wires, add a bare copper ground of appropriate size, and pull it all back in.  Also, be working under the supervision of a licensed electrician or the homeowner-occupant.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was this subpanel originally installed prior to NEC 2008 being adopted by your state? If so, the 3-wire connection may be "grandfathered" or "legal when installed, and not required to be upgraded" with neutral and ground combined (not a great idea).

Comment: @harper the NEC started requiring 4 wire in 99 there was a major upgrade to grounding and bonding requirements and the isolation of the neutral. Some states took a few years to adopt but prior to 99 3 wire was compliant.

Comment: @Ed Thanks, I had heard it was 2008.

Comment: @ Harper I have made this exact comment probably 100 times or more here I remember the date as this was when my local inspector recommended I get my supervising electrician license.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend why or how the broken wire is broken.

If the conduit is intact, you can attach the new wire to the bad wire and pull in the new wire - except that what you actually appear to need is to pull in **two** new wires - at which point it's probably safer to pull out all the wires, replace the bad one, add the new separate ground wire, and pull them all back in. If, of course, the conduit is large enough.

If the wire is broken because the conduit is broken, you'll have to find the point(s) where it's broken, excavate them, and fix it before you can replace (or repair, if you provide an access point when re-burying) the bad wire.

Right. If the conduit is metallic, that IS the ground "wire" and **no separate wire** is needed for that. The neutral bar needs to be isolated from the case at the sub-panel.

If this is recent work in the USA, you should also have recourse to the licensing board responsible for the electrician having a license if they have in fact installed a 3-wire feeder (in plastic conduit) on a **new** installation. Those don't have to be upgraded if they were installed when that was legal, but it hasn't been legal for a long time. Only if the area is so backwards that they have not adopted NEC 2008 or later, or there's a local change to the code removing the 4-wire requirement would that be legit. There are places where that could apply.

However, if you ONLY need 240VAC at the garage, you can (properly to code) use only 3 wires (hot, hot & ground) but that's unusual for most USA installations.

Comment: the garage has a bathroom and a refrigerator and a baseboard heater and a washer and dryer. I believe it needs 2 hots a neutral and a ground.  I don't want to dig up the customer's driveway. I have a route on the side of the driveway. I just thought I could run one feeder and use it with the other feeder that are still good. And the house is in the United States

Comment: "customer's driveway"  So they hired you to fix this?  Not sure how to respond to your comment.

Comment: I know in some states a licensed “handyman” or contractor can make repairs as in replace with the same type.